# FCKeditor not working on Mozilla

Tags: fckeditor, mozilla

I have uploaded my site to the server. FCKeditor is only working in Internet Exploder but not working on Mozilla. What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to stick to FCKeditor, while a better version is out there?
[CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) is replacing FCKeditor.

If you want to stick to CKEditor, check whether you've the latest version of FCKEditor: 2.6.6.